# In jQuery, how can I select different elements by the name attribute?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to loop through some elements in a form (radios, text boxes, and select boxes) and get the value from each element.  I am looping through by the name of each element (I don't think I can use ID because a group of radio buttons all have different IDs, but all have the same name).

Here are 2 selectors that encompass all the elements I need:

```
$("input[name=" + prop + "]")
$("select[name=" + prop + "]")
```

where prop is the loop iterator.

I want perform the same operation on both selectors, so I tried to combine them:

```
$("input[name=" + prop + "]", "select[name=" + prop + "]")
```

But that didn't work.

Is there a way to combine a search for both input elements and select elements in one selector?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have just one little mistake: You declared the two selectors as two different parameters instead of one parameter with the comma as part of the selector:

```
$("input[name=" + prop + "], select[name=" + prop + "]")
```

The way you wrote it uses the elements of the second selector parameter as the context the first selector parameter is resolved from.

Comment: Wow - I totally see what I did wrong.  I had copied and pasted the 2 selectors to make 1 selector, and I totally messed up on my quotes placement.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: You may also want to add `textarea`, and conceivably `button`.

Answer (score 5):

If the comma is included in the selector string it will work.  You could also do

```
$("input, select").filter("[name=" + prop + "]")
```

which eliminates writing "[name=" + prop + "]" twice.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to shoehorn everything you do into jQuery. The DOM Level 1 HTML standard gives you `HTMLFormElement.elements`, which is easy, fast and doesn't fail for unusual characters in `name` like a selector string would.

```
<form id="x" ...>
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <select name="foo"></select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var prop= 'foo';
    var form= $('#x')[0];
    var foos= form.elements[prop];
    alert(foos.length+' '+foos[0].type+' '+foos[1].type);  // 2 text select-one
</script>
```

Comment: That's a good tip - I fall into that trap a lot, actually.  It's good to take a step back and remember the language that jQuery is written in.

Comment: As a bonus, this will catch other form fields that aren't inputs or selects (like a textarea), in case the form is changed somewhere down the road.